# Shell Script: How to calculate the number of bytes transmitted on a network from a single network intense application?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking

Shell Scripting: How to calculate the number of bytes uploaded to a remote node?

1) I have used IPTRAF command it can capture all the data but when I try to run the script from a local system using vxargs(python), it doesn't work. 
2) I have also tried to use IFTOP command but it doesn't save the output to a file. 
3) Also /proc/net/dev doesn't work because its captures some extra packets.

Does tcpdump command capture only the number of bytes/packets of the data load transmitted or does the data transmitted will have some headers attached to it?

I would like to capture only data packets from my running network intensive application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done trivially. See http://mutrics.iitis.pl/tracedump for a program that seems to accomplish this. However it has not been updated since 2012 and only works on 32 bit arch.

A crude solution could be to run the application through `strace` and then summarize the return values of the relevant syscalls like `write` and `sendto`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you want, but if you run the process with specified user, let's say appuser, you can add a firewall rule which will count the traffic for you.
example:

`iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner appuser -j ACCEPT`

check how much packet and bytes sent out by the user:

`iptables -vL OUTPUT |sed -n '2p;/appuser/p'`